# DropDownList em views asp.net mvc da erro na validação

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Em uma `view razor` do `asp.net mvc` eu tenho uma `dropdownlist` com o seguinte código:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Banco, (SelectList) ViewBag.Banco, new {@class = "form-control"})
```

Mesmo selecionando o valor, quando valido no `controller`, como `ModelState.IsValid`, sempre da erro, diz que o valor selecionado é inválido, mas, na verdade, não é, o `Id` selecionado está correto. Tem como ignorar a validação deste campo ou consertar isso?

Comment: Aonde você está verificando esse ModelState.IsValid?

Comment: no controller, na action que persiste as informações no banco.

Comment: Por favor, poste exatamente o que seu ModelState está retornando como erro de validação.

Comment: Está retornando esta mensagem: "The value '1' is invalid." 1 é o Id do banco selecionado.

Comment: Tem como colocar o código do controler também?

Comment: Aproveita e coloca o código do Model tambem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, eu estava fazendo errado, alterei para apontar para o Id do Banco e não para o banco em si e funcionou:

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Banco.Id, (SelectList) ViewBag.Banco, new {@class = "form-control"})

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer no escopo de uma Action que recebe o modelo do seu fomulário submetido

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Exclude="Banco")]CompanyDto model)
{
    // ...
}
```

Pode descriminar a propriedade no escopo da sua model tambem visto que quando desta forma  sera influenciado em toda a 
aplicação e nao somente na Action que esta sendo usada.

```
[Bind(Exclude="Propriedade_1,Propriedade_2,Propriedade_3")]
public class CompanyDto
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Propriedade_1 { get; set; }
  public string Propriedade_2 { get; set; }
  public string Propriedade_3 { get; set; }
  // ...
}
```

Pode tambem como filtro de um propriedade de um objeto model exemplo

```
public class CompanyDto
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [Exclude]
  public string Propriedade_1 { get; set; }
  public string Propriedade_2 { get; set; }
  public string Propriedade_3 { get; set; }
  // ...
}
```

Outra forma de verificar é colocar um breakpoint na Action que recebe os dados e antes disso no browser precionar F12 e verificar o value do item que tem a propriedade 'selected' do seu dropdown antes de você submeter o formulário, para a Action.

Comment: Achei muito boa a sua resposta Rodrigo, muito interessante, mas consegui fazer o que eu queria, obrigado.